# Python3 - Invalid character in identifier (within formula)

Tags: python, formula, identifier

The 2nd left bracket is returning an invalid character in identifier. The program's expected to print out the monthly salary for an employee. I checked my indentation and it seems fine, and removed brackets here and there to substitute.

```
#Input hoursWorked
#Input hourPay
#Ask “Consultancy income? (Leave blank if none)”
#   If value:
#       Input consultFee
#       monthlySalary = ((hourPay - (hourPay * 0.1)) * hoursWorked) + (consultFee – (consultFee * 0.2))
#   Elif no value:
#       monthlySalary = hoursWorked * hourPay
#print (“The monthly wage is $”,monthlySalary)

hoursWorked = input ("Hours worked: ")
hourPay = input ("Hour pay: $")

consultFee = input ("Consultant fee? (Leave blank if none): $")
if consultFee is '':
    monthlySalary = hourPay * 0.1
elif consultFee is not '':
    monthlySalary = ((hourPay - (hourPay * 0.1)) * hoursWorked) + (consultFee – (consultFee * 0.2))

print ("The monthly salary is: $",(int(monthlySalary)))
```

Comment: as an aside, use `==` to test for equivalency (`e.g. consultFree == ''`) not `is`. `is` tests for identity, so `'' is not False` but `'' == False`

Comment: 2nd left bracket here oops: (consultFee – **(** consultFee * 0.2))

Comment: @AdamSmith I changed the inputs to int(input("Hurr")) after realising, but that still doesn't really help with the invalid character in identifier :/

Comment: I retyped the monthlySalary line and the error went away.

Comment: What's your text editor? It may be converting `-` to m-dashes.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign you are using at that position isn't a regular minus (hyphen-minus) but an en-dash. Earlier in the same line you have a regular minus. It's bizarre to me that you would have both in the same file. You need to use a text editor that is oriented toward programming, or at least toward plain, unformatted text.

Comment: I had the same problem using a common programming text editor.  The problem originated from pasting a number from wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha! That's a tricky error.

```
>>> original = "–" # the second minus sign
>>> new = "-" # a regular minus sign
>>> ord(original)
8211
>>> ord(new)
45
>>> print(original == new)
False
```

My guess is that whatever text editor you're using automatically substituted the minus sign (`-`) with an n-dash (`–`). It's almost imperceptibly different! I would have beat myself up over this bug for ages, also.